# selecting data from a column and display them in different columns based on their values

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to select a value from a table like the following example:

```
user   id
----------
a       1
b       1
c       3
d       2
a       3
```

and the result will be like the following:

```
user  id_1  id_2  id_3
-----------------------
a      1     NULL   3
b      1     NULL   NULL
c      NULL  NULL   3
d      NULL  2      NULL
```

so basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to get all the users with `id's ==1` to a column and the users with `id ==2` to another column and users with `id ==3` to a third column and the users are duplicated like the case for user `'a'` when it showed once with `id=1` and `id=3` and I want to capture this duplication in the resulting table.

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a pivot.  You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select user,
       max(case when id = 1 then id end) as id_1,
       max(case when id = 2 then id end) as id_2,
       max(case when id = 3 then id end) as id_3
from table t
group by user
order by user;
```

Comment: I have another question, I'm trying to put zeros instead of Nulls in the id_1, id_2 and id_3 columns .. I tried to use COALESCE like `select user, max case when id =1 then coalesce(id,0) end) as id_1 ...`

Comment: @user1762447 . . . Just add `else 0` to each of the `case` statements.